# how to put ajax loader while image loads itself

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

how to use ajax loader is my question i am new to ajax. i have a function which work to change image when user click on thumbnail image but image are heavy so i want ajax till the second image load itself. i have created loader.gif now i just want to know how to use this image as a loader.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function (){
        jQuery('#data').find('img').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).click(function (){
                var crd = jQuery(this).attr('title');
                jQuery('#bigimg').fadeOut('slow', function (){
                    jQuery(this).find('#imnew').attr('src', 'images/' + crd +".jpg")
                }).fadeIn()
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="bigimg">
    <img src="images/bigImage1.jpg" id="imnew" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="data">
    <div class="sub">
        <div class="1">
            <img src="images/thumb1.png" width="117" height="74" title="bigImage1" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="2">
            <img src="images/thumb2.png" width="117" height="74" title="bigImage2" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="3">
            <img src="images/thumb3.png" width="117" height="74" title="bigImage3" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="4">
            <img src="images/thumb4.png" width="117" height="74" title="bigImage4" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="5">
            <img src="images/thumb1.png" width="117" height="74" title="bigImage1" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="6">
            <img src="images/thumb2.png" width="117" height="74" title="bigImage2" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="7">
            <img src="images/thumb3.png" width="117" height="74" title="bigImage3" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="8">
            <img src="images/thumb4.png" width="117" height="74" title="bigImage4" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jQuery.load to tell you when the image has finished loading.

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object. http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function (){
        jQuery('#data').find('img').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).click(function (){
                var crd = jQuery(this).attr('title');
                // $('#loader').show();
                jQuery('#bigimg').fadeOut('slow', function (){
                    jQuery(this).find('#imnew').attr('src', 'images/' + crd +".jpg")
                    .load(function() { 
                                    $('#loader').hide();
                                    $('#bigimg').fadeIn()

                   });
                })
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Give all your thumbnails the same classname, and then:

```
        $('.thumbnail').click(function (){
            var thumbNail = $(this);
            var thumbPath = $(this).attr('src');
            var crd = $(this).attr('title');
            $(this).attr('src', 'images/loader.gif');
            $('#bigimg').fadeOut('slow', function (){
               $(this).load(function() {
                  $(this).fadeIn();
                  $(thumbNail).attr('src', thumbPath);
               });
               $(this).attr('src', crd);
            })

        })
```